# Published NuGet packages not showing in remote NuGet Feed?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I am setting up a NuGet server to host our packages internally. I followed the steps listed below:

https://docs.nuget.org/create/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds

but having issues.

I have a site setup in IIS on the TFS server and can navigate to the URL successfully. I see the "You are running NuGet Server 2.8.5 but the link to view your packages doesn't show any packages. However, I can publish packages successfully from the visual studio project to the remote package path which is the normal inetpub\wwwroot etc. The packages show up in the path correctly and also show up in visual studio in manage packages menu. Anyone have an idea why they aren't showing up in the package feed URL?

I would greatly appreciate any help I could get.

Thanks,

Comment: I have the exact issue. It's telling me the packages have been pushed successfully but I don't see them.

Comment: My NuGet Server is now working. My issue was web config file package path location. I changed it to the Default "~/Packages" and it works now.

Comment: Ah yeah same here, i accidentally used my default key as part of the URL and they were being pushed nowhere. I would have thought if the URL didn't make sense it would show an error.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues. I was able to get it working by using the full file path in packagesPath key of the web.config. I could not use a relative path.